# How to Limit Upload Image From Android to database MySQL

Tags: java, android

I have problem when I want to set `LIMIT UPLOAD IMAGE` in KB (kilobytes), example 200KB.

```
private void uploadImage(){
    if (bitmap.getByteCount() > 2 * 1024 * 1024){
        H.T(AddFotoActivity.this,"Foto Maksimal 200KB");
    }
}
```

Is that true if I use `2 * 1024 * 1024` to set 200KB image file ?

Comment: @Ahamed so i must change it 200*1024 to set 200KB limit upload image sir?

Comment: Check like if(bitmap.length()/1024 <200){        H.T(AddFotoActivity.this,"Foto Maksimal 200KB");
}

Comment: i try your code sir, `if(bitmap.length()/1024 <200){ H.T(AddFotoActivity.this,"Foto Maksimal 200KB"); }`
but error like this : cannot resolve method 'length()'